# Cycle through cells, adding those that fit criteria to a list/string using VBA?

Tags: vba, email, excel, excel-2013

I am new to VBA (and have only a bit of training in java), and have hit a wall.

The ultimate goal is to cycle through a range of cells containing names, comparing the value of an adjacent cell to a constant.  If conditions are met, the original cells should be added to a list that will be ingested by another formula responsible for drafting an email.  This will be repeated daily, and the values coinciding with each name will change.

I have figured out how to cycle through the range using a variable that adds EVERY name to the "TO" line of the email draft, but don't know how to add conditions to the cycle so it only adds the desired ones.  **Essentially, I believe the only thing I need help with is the "sTo" variable.**  Thanks!

```
Sub Draft_Email()

Dim emailRng As Range, cl As Range
Dim adjCellRng As Range, cmp As Range

Dim sTo As String
Dim day As String
Dim EmailBody As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim k As String

k = 85

day = Format(Date, "dddd mmmm d")
EmailBody = "Blah Blah"

Set emailRng = Worksheets("Briefing Order").Range("D4:D31,G4:G31,J4:J31,M4:M31")

For Each cl In emailRng
    **cmp = cl.Offset(0, -1)**
    If cmp >= k Then
        sTo = sTo & ";" & cl.Value & "WindTemp-DG@wnco.com"
    End If
Next cl

sTo = Mid(sTo, 2)

'..Draft Email where .BCC = sTo

End Sub
```

Comment: Personally I don't like working with ranges if I can help it, i'd take the range into an array and work with that, quicker, simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set emailRng = Worksheets("Briefing Order").Range("D4:D31,G4:G31,J4:J31,M4:M31")
Set adjCellRng = Worksheets("Briefing Order").Range("E4:E31,H4:H31,K4:K31,L4:L31")

'something like the following... 
For i = 1 to emailRng.size 'whatever the limit variable is 
    cl = emailRng(i)
    cmp = adjCellRng(i)
    if cmp==k then
         sTo = sTo & ";" & cl.Value & "Department@work.com"
    end if
Next

sTo = Mid(sTo, 2)
```

Comment: Hey jdl,

Can you elaborate a bit on what this means/how you came to this?  Is "i" an index and does it need to be initialized (I'm getting a mismatch error)?  Is "cmp" the value of the adjacent cell?    What is the limit variable/"emailRng.size"? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would change the jdl code with

```
Set emailRng = Worksheets("Brifing Order").Range("D4:D31,G4:G31,J4:J31,M4,M31")

'something like the following... 
For each c1 in emailRng.cells 
    cmp = c1.offset(0,1)
    if cmp==k then
         sTo = sTo & ";" & cl.Value & "Department@work.com"
    end if
Next

sTo = Mid(sTo, 2)
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit on what this means/how you came to this? I've been battling with it but I'm still getting a "Object variable or With block variable not set" error in the "For Each..." line, and I have no clue how to fix it.

    `Dim emailRng As Range, cl As Range
    Dim adjCellRng As Range, cmp As Range
    Dim sTo As String
    Dim day As String
    Dim EmailBody As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim k As String
    
    k = 85

Set emailRng = Worksheets("Briefing Order").Range("D4:D31,G4:G31,J4:J31,M4:M31")`